# Accessing blob storage using ClientID only works when run on windows account with azure access

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-blob-storage

I have written a script to archive files from our local server onto cloud blob storage with hierarchical namespace enabled.  As you can see I am using an azure application ClientID to authenticate.  When I run the script under my account that has full access to the storage account it works as expected.  However when I run the script under an account that doesn't have access to azure AD I get the below error.

It does successfully authenticate and when I run $StorageContext | Select-Object -Property * it does show the login as the same account for the clientid and that clientid does have full access to the filesystem I'm trying to act on.  I just don't understand why this script runs under my login but not another.

Status: 403 (This request is not authorized to perform this operation.)
ErrorCode: AuthorizationFailure

```
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($ClientId, (ConvertTo-SecureString $ClientSecret -AsPlainText -Force))
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -Tenant $TenantId -Subscription $SubscriptionId -ServicePrincipal -Scope Process

$StorageContext = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -UseConnectedAccount

$dirname \root\folder
$NewFolder = Get-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $StorageContext -FileSystem $FileSystemName -Path $dirname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

Comment: Navigate to the `Networking` in your storage account, check if the firewall is set to allow access from all networks?

Comment: @JoyWang I'll get an administrator to check.  However both tests are being run on the same machine so wouldn't the network be the same?

Comment: If you are using the same service principal to auth(i.e. client id and secret you used), this is the only possibility, also make sure you are using the correct one to auth, run [`Clear-AzContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/clear-azcontext?view=azps-5.5.0) first, then use `Connect-AzAccount` to login, also remove `-Scope Process` from it.

Comment: @JoyWang thanks.  I was able to run this from another computer successfully on both accounts as well as run it using another storage account successfully.  That all confirms that it must be a problem with the network permissions/firewall/proxy.  Your help troubleshooting is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to the Networking in your storage account, check if the firewall is set to allow access from all networks.

If you are using the same service principal to auth(i.e. client id and secret you used), the networking/firewall issue is the only possibility, also make sure you are using the correct one to auth, run [`Clear-AzContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.accounts/clear-azcontext?view=azps-5.5.0) first, then use `Connect-AzAccount` to login, also remove `-Scope Process` from it.